# how to set transparent pixel to white in java using opencv?

Tags: python, java, opencv

what's the equivalent code in java using opencv ?

```
#make mask of where the transparent bits are
trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 0

#replace areas of transparency with white and not transparent
image[trans_mask] = [255, 255, 255, 255]
```

updated:

I don't get it, why people downvote this. the "easy" solution is so clear that you assign each pixel in a loop, but that would not as efficient as this way. I searched for it and got no clues. why these people don't understand this question in the first place and try to discuss it. if you guys don't know it just leave it.

if you try to process images in java efficiently, this question is useful to you.

Comment: Please attempt a solution to the problem, then update your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this, thanks for new bing

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(imgPath, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
Mat dst = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
Core.inRange(img, new Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 0), dst);
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
Core.add(img, dst, dst);
```